# What is ServletWrappingController in spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

i am trying to know about ServletWrappingController in Spring.

my questions is

How to implement ServletWrappingController in an application?

Is this ServletWrappingController class should extend in Controller class

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

`ServletWrappingController` is a class in the Spring API - the documentation is [right there](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html):

> Spring Controller implementation that wraps a servlet instance which it manages internally. Such a wrapped servlet is not known outside of this controller; its entire lifecycle is covered here (in contrast to ServletForwardingController).
>
> Useful to invoke an existing servlet via Spring's dispatching infrastructure, for example to apply Spring HandlerInterceptors to its requests.

Comment: Is that ServletWrappingController should apply HandlerInterceptor?(i.e) Is interceptors property is important when we implementing ServletWrappingController?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html), a `ServletWrappingController` is a controller that wraps an existing, standard Java servlet.

It's primary reason for being seems to be to allow developers to leverage the functionalities of Spring (like handler interceptors) while still using other servlet-based technologies like your own custom servlets or, as mentioned in the doc, the Struts framework.

Comment: Now i understood the use of ServletWrappingController. Can you please give some examples regarding ServletWrappingController in Spring?

Comment: @Mohan - can you post the example you found?  I'm trying to implement this and am struggling to get mine to work...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to implement ServletWrappingController. In this case I'm wrapping Prometheus' MetricsServlet but you can easily modify this for any existing servlet.

```
@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiguration {

    /**
     * Register the metricsController.
     * @return Returns the ServletWrappingController for the Prometheus
     * MetricsServlet.
     */
    @Bean
    public ServletWrappingController metricsController() throws Exception {
        ServletWrappingController controller = new ServletWrappingController();
        controller.setServletClass(MetricsServlet.class);
        controller.setBeanName("metricsController");
        controller.afterPropertiesSet();

        return controller;
    }

    /**
     * Map /metrics to the metricsController.
     * @return Returns the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.
     */
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping metricsControllerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
        urlProperties.put("/metrics", "metricsController");
        mapping.setMappings(urlProperties);
        mapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);

        return mapping;
    }

}
```

If you want to do it with XML instead of annotations there are examples in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html) (as mentioned by @pap).

There is also some good info on how to do the mapping part of it [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-handler-mappings).